# Final model after spacy train created with whole data or not?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy train to create a new pos tagger model for Serbian language. Therefore, I use two files: *train.json* and *test.json*. After 30 iterations spacy produces, among others, two models: **best model** and **final model**.

I understand that the **best model** originates from the iteration that achieved best score on a *test.json* dataset. What is the **final model**? Is it created on the whole data (*train.json* + *test.json*) using best model parameters found during 30 iterations (parameters used for the **best model**)?

If not, how can best parameters after training be retrieved and how then to train on the whole data (train.json + test.json)?